# About NSDateComponents:Why I can't get the correct day component?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I want get day component from localDate, [NSDate localDate] just transform the GMT into local time.

```
NSDate *localDate=[NSDate localDate];

// localDate:2017-03-13 18:35:35 +0000
NSLog(@"localDate:%@",localDate);
NSInteger dayComponentLocal=[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:(NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:localDate];
NSLog(@"dayComponentLocal:%ld",(long)dayComponentLocal);
```

But why the output is 14?

There is the implement of [NSDate localDate]:

```
NSDate *date=[NSDate date];
NSTimeZone *zone=[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSInteger interval=[zone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSDate *localDate=[date dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
return localDate;
```

And there is another error when I want to get the first weekday of current month, there is the code:

```
NSDate *date=[NSDate localDate];
NSInteger dayComponents=[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:(NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:date];
NSInteger secondsInADay=24*60*60;
NSDate *firstDay=[date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-((dayComponents-1)*secondsInADay)];
NSInteger weekdayComponent=[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:(NSCalendarUnitWeekday) fromDate:firstDay];
NSLog(@"firstDay:%@",firstDay);
NSLog(@"weekday Of firstDay:%ld",weekdayComponent);
```

due to the wrong dayComponents, I subtract one more day from 'localDate' and get the wrong firstDay '2017-02-28 20:09:32 +0000' rather than the correct answer '2017-03-01 20:09:32 +0000'. 2-28 is Tuesday, but I get 4, which means Wednesday,
Why?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the number of seconds from GMT in `localDate`. As your time zone is positive you need to *subtract* the seconds (`-interval`) to get UTC.

By the way **never ever** use 86400 for date math. Use the date calculation methods of `NSCalendar`

For example you get the first weekday of the current month with

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
// calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
NSDate *startDate;
NSTimeInterval interval;
[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth startDate:&startDate interval:&interval forDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger weekday = [calendar  component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:startDate];
NSLog(@"%ld", weekday);
```

To get the date related to UTC uncomment the time zone line.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the time components from the date before taking the day component.
Try this code

```
 NSDate *localDate=[NSDate localDate];
    // localDate:2017-03-13 18:35:35 +0000
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: localDate];
    localDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: strDate];
   NSInteger dayComponentLocal=[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:(NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:localDate];
   NSLog(@"dayComponentLocal:%ld",(long)dayComponentLocal);
```

You will get output 13. This occur maybe because of difference in time zone